# Can big strings cause large object heap fragmentation?

Tags: .net, string, memory-management, large-object-heap

Can big strings (85kb+) cause large object heap fragmentation like large arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can probably safely assume these are not literals: yes, they are stored in the LOH.  .NET 4.0 introduced ropes for StringBuilder, specifically designed to keep short-lived builder buffers out of the LOH.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in 3.5?